# Flutter how to test Either<Failure,List<Object>>

Tags: flutter-test, either

it seems to have the same value with matcher but still can't pass the test probably cuz of the memory address stuff. can anyone let me know how i can test the result when a list is in Either<< Right >>

```
test('get board list from remote data source', () async {
   when(mockBoardRemoteDataSource.getBoards())
       .thenAnswer((_) async => tBoardModels);

   final result = await repository.getBoards();

   verify(mockBoardRemoteDataSource.getBoards());
   expect(result, equals(Right(toBoards)));   
   // Either<Failure, List<BoardInfo>> result;
   // (new) Right<dynamic, List<BoardInfo>> Right(List<BoardInfo> _r)
});
```

//console result

```
Expected: Right<dynamic, List<BoardInfo>>:<Right([_$_BoardInfo(1, name1, address1), _$_BoardInfo(2, name2, address2)])>
Actual: Right<Failure, List<BoardInfo>>:<Right([_$_BoardInfo(1, name1, address1), _$_BoardInfo(2, name2, address2)])>
    
package:test_api                                                                   expect
package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart 455:16                                 expect
test\features\nurban_honey\data\repositories\board_repository_impl_test.dart 58:9  main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>
```

//BoardInfo Implementation

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'board_info.freezed.dart';

@freezed
class BoardInfo extends Equatable with _$BoardInfo {
  BoardInfo._();
  factory BoardInfo(int id, String name, String address) = _BoardInfo;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [id, name, address];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Jay, his answer helps me to made my resolution.

This is how i made the test act:

```
// Act
var results = (await repository.fetch()).fold(
    (failure) => failure,
    (response) => response,
);
```

Then I made a type expectation, matching to the failure type declared on my use case:

In the case of the successful execution

```
// Assert
expect(results, isA<ResultType>());
```

In the case of the failure expectation

```
// Assert
expect(results, isA<FailureType>());
```

The entire test case looks like the following

```
test('On successful execution, should returns a SuccessResultType', () async {
  
  // Arrange
  repository = MyUseCaseRepository();

  // Act
  var results = (await repository.fetch()).fold(
    (failure) => failure,
    (response) => response,
  );

  // Assert
  expect(results, isA<SuccessResultType>());
});
```

I hope this approach can help anybody!

Answer (score 0):

I've made the test pass by doing this:

```
result.fold(
       (l) => null,
       (resultR) => Right(toBoards)
           .fold((l) => null, (matcherR) => expect(resultR, matcherR)));
```

is there better way to do it?

Comment: or this : 
result.fold((l) => null, (r) => expect(r, toBoards));

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).